# restar recorrido en doble ciclo for, eliminando datos ya encontrados, subtract traversal in double loop for, deleting data already found

Tags: python, bucles, data, rendimiento

¿alguna sugerencia para optimizar el codigo?
en teoria, se hace break al datos mayores y pregunta si el dato actual ya existe desde una lista en orden reverse, ademas elimina los datos ya sumados. pero deja unos datos residuo, el rendimiento queda de 1 hora a 7 minutos.

¿any suggestions to optimize the code?
in theory, it breaks the largest data and asks if the current data already exists from a list in reverse order

iDupes:
se dividen en dos dataframes, de semestre1 y semester2.
iDupes usa uno y luego el otro.
[image: Dos Listas, se escoje una]

```
 copiaLimite2=iDupes.copy()     
 copiaLimite2['Codigo SNIES del programa'] =copiaLimite2['Codigo SNIES del programa'].astype(int)
 copiaLimite2['Admitidos'] =copiaLimite2['Admitidos'].astype(int)
 copiaLimite2['Semestre'] =copiaLimite2['Semestre'].astype(int)
 copiaLimite2=copiaLimite2.sort_values(by=['Codigo SNIES del programa'])     

 for0=copiaLimite2
 for2=copiaLimite2
 
 porcentajeVisual=len(for0)
 
 sumatoria=0
 porcentajesum=0
 seen=set()

 inscritosColumna=0
 añoColumna=1
 codigoSniesColumna=2
 semestreColumna=4     
 
 # Iteración por filas del DataFrame:
 for indice_fila, fila0 in for0.iterrows():   
  sumatoria=fila0[inscritosColumna]

  """
  ordenar datso de mayor a menor
  """     
  """
  elimitar datos encontrados de for1
  """
  if fila0[codigoSniesColumna] in sorted(seen, reverse=True):        
    porcentajesum+=1     
    continue
  
  if(porcentajesum % 100 == 0):
   print(porcentajesum,"~~"*20,fila0[codigoSniesColumna],round((porcentajesum/porcentajeVisual),2),len(for2))
  for indice_fila1, fila1 in for2.iterrows():
    if(fila0[codigoSniesColumna]<fila1[codigoSniesColumna]):
      break
 
    if fila0[codigoSniesColumna]==fila1[codigoSniesColumna] and fila0[añoColumna]==fila1[añoColumna] and fila0[semestreColumna]==fila1[semestreColumna] and indice_fila1!=indice_fila :   
      sumatoria = fila1[inscritosColumna]+fila0[inscritosColumna]
 
      
      if fila1[codigoSniesColumna] in sorted(seen, reverse=True):
       pass
 
      else: 
        seen.add(fila1[codigoSniesColumna])
        for2=for2.drop(indice_fila) 
 
      for0=for0.drop(indice_fila1) 
      for0.loc[indice_fila, 'Admitidos'] = sumatoria
      for2=for2.drop(indice_fila1) 
    if(fila1[codigoSniesColumna]>fila0[codigoSniesColumna]):
      for2=for2.drop(indice_fila)  
  
  porcentajesum+=1    
  #print("sumatoria",sumatoria)  
  fila0[inscritosColumna]=sumatoria
 
 
  seen1=sorted(seen, reverse=True)
  seen=set(seen1)
 dataFrameDupes3.append(for0)
```

he trabajado un par de dias en este codigo.
perdon por la documentacion, si recibe apoyo lo puedo ir actualizando.

Salida de Codigo: genera el dataframe de cada semestre
[image: salida codigo: 2 dataframes]

I have worked a couple of days on this code.
Sorry for the documentation, if you receive support I can update it.

Comment: Para ayudate tienes que publicar un código completo, que sea llegar y copiar para poder ejecutar. También debes aportar los datos de entrada y una muestra de la salida que buscas para poder chequear que la respuesta sea correcta.

Comment: Además, no es necesario que pongas el texto en inglés, estamos en [es.so]. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: para ejecutar el codigo se necesita cargar un dataframe en <limite > lo de ingles no los sabia que no importaba, y agregue entrada , salida nuevos, xd